# Python Dictionary result parsing in mac

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Hello I am exploring AWS python library boto3 ,

I am running a sample script which will list s3 buckets in my aws accound:

```
import boto3

aws = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="sand")

s3_client = aws.client("s3")

response = s3_client.list_buckets()

print(response)
```

The result I am getting is an Dictionary as following:

[image]

It is a bit difficult to understand the dictionary in a proper way, As I am new to python can anyone tell me how can I better visualize this dictionary data in terminal, I know I can take this result and parse it online but is there any other way to print the result in better readable way??

Or any other suggestions???

I wish to see like this as result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Python lets you pretty print dict stuff:

```
import json
print json.dumps({'a':2, 'b':{'x':3, 'y':{'t1': 4, 't2':5}}},
                 sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```